# Display a React Component as a string

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to display a helper string text with a react component. The string is part of an array of messages that get displayed on a screen. In this particular string, I'm using an icon for part of the string. The icon is a component. However, I keep getting back [object, object].

What I've tried...

```
`Click on the ${(<EyeIcon />)} to view the password you have entered.`,
```

Also just displaying the icon,

```
<EyeIcon />
```

I've even tried making the component into a export function.

```
EyeIcon()
```

But I can't seem to get it to appear.

Comment: EyeIcon is a component and not a string. It is the expected behavior. Now, if you move your string to JSX code, this can work. Everything depends on where you want to show this string. Is it part of some JSX? Can you share the code where you use this string?

Comment: No, it's part of just a regular JavaScript helper function I have. There is a series of messages that are in an array that I have that get displayed on a screen. For one message I need an icon which is a component.

Comment: What are you expecting in the place of `${(<EyeIcon />)}`? Its HTML?

Comment: You can't just interpolate a component instantiation with a string template. Move the jsx outside your text block;
`<div> Click on the <Icon /> </div>`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, there's some difference between a function, and a function component.

##### function

```
  const eyeIcon = s => `Click on ${s}`
```

This is a function that you can plugin to output a new string based on `s`.

##### function component

```
  const EyeIcon = ({ s }) => <span>Click on {s}</span>
```

This is a function component that you can use via

```
  const Title = () => {
    return <EyeIcon s="abc" />
  }
```

A function component is a function, but it needs to be invoked to produce an element (not a string), therefore the return statement is not a string (Even you output a string there, it'll be wrapped into an element for you).

NOTE:

it's a bit confusing if it's your first time into functional programming, but just watch out for the input and output. The function component input argument is a `props` object, and it returns a DOM-like element (called React element). There's quite a bit ES6 syntax to confuse you further.

Answer (score 1):

If this string is part of some conditions try this option:

```
<>Click on the (<EyeIcon />) to view the password you have entered.</>
```